# MS Access Using ComboBox Value in SQL Field

Tags: sql, ms-access, combobox

Trying to set up a query where one of the fields is selected by the value in a combobox.  Can't figure out the right syntax.  I'm in the SQL view of the query builder, using the following:

```
SELECT Deviations.Deviation, Deviations.Rev, Deviations.Title, Deviations.Issued, Deviations.ExpiryDate, Deviations.ExpiryHours, Deviations.ExpOther, Deviations.Active, Deviations.[Forms]![DeviationSelectionForm]![cmbAircraft]
FROM Deviations
WHERE Deviations.[Forms]![DeviationSelectionForm]![cmbAircraft]=True
ORDER BY Deviations.Deviation DESC
```

The combo box selects the tail number of the aircraft which is a checkbox in the table.  There are multiple aircraft tail numbers as checkbox fields.  So if there were no combobox and I wanted the query to use as example aircraft 416, the query would be:

```
SELECT Deviations.Deviation, Deviations.Rev, Deviations.Title, Deviations.Issued, Deviations.ExpiryDate, Deviations.ExpiryHours, Deviations.ExpOther, Deviations.Active, Deviations.[416]
FROM Deviations
WHERE Deviations.[416]=True
ORDER BY Deviations.Deviation DESC
```

When I test this query it works as I need it to.

So the question is how to I create the query with the combobox in a form identifying the field name of a table?

Answer (score 1):

Build the Query SQL viacode in the combobox afterUpdate event.

```
Dim strSql as String
strSql = "SELECT Deviations.Deviation, Deviations.Rev, Deviations.Title, Deviations.Issued, " _
& "Deviations.ExpiryDate, Deviations.ExpiryHours, Deviations.ExpOther, " _
& "Deviations.Active, Deviations." & Me!cmbAircraft _
& " FROM Deviations " _
& "WHERE Deviations." & Me!cmbAircraft & " =True " _
& "ORDER BY Deviations.Deviation DESC"
CurrentDb.QueryDefs(<yourqueryname>).SQL = strSql
```

That said, it seems like you have built a spreadsheet instead of a database.
Your tables are not normalized. Aircraft should be records, not columns. I suggest you read up on database design and normalization.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I believe that may work.  As for the database design, I hear what you're saying but have had to structure it this way.  I have a table with aircraft numbers which isn't used in this case.  The table I'm dealing with is based on a deviation for aircraft maintenance which might apply to one or many different aircraft so I have columns with check boxes for each of the aircraft in the deviations table.  So when a deviation is published against multiple aircraft, I enter the deviation information and select to which aircraft it applies.  Open to suggestions though.

Comment: Three tables: 1. Aircraft (AircraftID, <all needed fields relating to the aircraft>) 2. Deviations (DeviationID, <all needed fields for a deviation>) 3. AircraftDeviations (AircraftID, DeviationID)

Comment: Thanks!  Reading up on it now.  Not entirely sure yet how to implement it in this scenario but am hoping your advice has led me in the right direction.  My gut instincts told me early on that my db design might be flawed.  To that end, can you suggest what my deviation form might look like?  Right now I have each aircraft represented as a checkbox on the deviation form, with each checkbox populating the underlying table.  Is this still appropriate or should it be a combobox/listbox created from the aircraft table?  In which case, how do would the AircraftDeviations table be populated?

Comment: Your current structure with the checkboxes is not appropriate. You need three tables as I've outlined. You should not need to add new fields when you get a new aircraft or deviation. Aircraft table contains one record for each aircraft, Deviations contains one record for each deviation and AircraftDefiations contains one record for each combination of aircraft plus deviation. You then use a query to join them to view which aircraft has which deviations.

Comment: Always use forms for data entry. On your Deviations form, have a subform bound to AircraftDeviations with combobox whose rowsource is aircraft. Or on aircraft form a subform bound to AircraftDeviations  with combobox whose rowsource is deviations. Or both. It's all pretty basic.